# Remove vertical space induced by substack

Tags: math-mode, align, vertical-spacing, substack

With the `aligned` environment one can split equations across multiple lines. When using substack, more space might be required by a line, shifting any subsequent line further:

```
\begin{align}
  \begin{aligned}
    F(M) = \bigcup_{\substack{x, y \in M\\ x \neq y}} \big\{\{x,y\} \mid& \text{long condition 1},\\
  & \text{long condition 2} \big\}
  \end{aligned}
\end{align}
```

[image: vertical space due to substack]

Is there a way to remove or ignore the vertical space occupied by the substack (indicated by the red arrow)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could `\smash` the `\substack` but in this case I would simply use a different arrangement for the `aligned` environment.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
F(M) = \bigcup_{\substack{x, y \in M\\ x \neq y}} \bigl\{ \{x,y\} \mid
\begin{aligned}[t]
  & \text{long condition 1}, \\
  & \text{long condition 2} \bigr\} 
\end{aligned}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Please note also the use of `\bigl\{` and `\bigr\}` instead of `\big\{` and `\big\}`.

Comment: Wow that was a fast answer. Thank you very much, it worked and was exactly what I was looking for. :) Will accept you answer in a minute.

Comment: The \bigr| was not intended. Good catch. Removed it now.